# Get global variables from file as dict?

Tags: python, import, global

I've got a file, `constants.py`, that contains a bunch of global constants. Is there a way I can grab all of them as dict, for just this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be simple:

```
import constants
print(constants.__dict__)
```

Comment: Wow, this is way simpler than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import constants

constants_dict = {}
for constant in dir(constants):
    constants_dict[constant] = getattr(constants, constant)
```

I'm not sure I see the point of this though.  How is writing `constants_dict['MY_CONSTANT']` any better/easier/more readable than `constants.MY_CONSTANT`?

EDIT:

Based on the comments, I see some potential uses now.

Here's another way to write the above, depending on how compact you want it.

```
constants_dict = dict((c, getattr(constants, c)) for c in dir(constants))
```

EDIT2:

[cji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460864/get-global-variables-from-file-as-dict/3461036#3461036) for the win!  `constants.__dict__`

Comment: One thing I can think of is using computed value as a key - but then there are `getattr` and `setattr` functions.

Comment: Well, I can answer that for my current project (though my problem was functions, not variables): we had to reference the variable (function, in my case) across three socket connections, a USB connection, and a radio signal (that's the full path from function call to function execution). The destination needed a dictionary of string:function pairings to know what function to call, when only given a function name and the parameter values to use. More specifically, we paired the string:function, and then paired byte:string, which let us pair byte:function (severely cutting down on packet size).

Comment: I'm passing the constants off to my template... the `constants_dict` part will drop off, and I can use my constants directly.

Comment: @myself - rationale given in comments above made me rethink this problem and then easiest solution appeared at once - I used `__dict__` attribute quite a few times to avoid writing `object.something` (instead of just `something`) in Django templates - it's not elegant, but it works. In my case I updated `context` with `__dict__` of some object instance - but it is applicable to modules as well. It will fail, however, if you have class with `__slots__` defined - and probably when you try to query some package (`__init__.py` without `__all__`).